# Error: Incompatible versions detected, cypress-grep 3.0.0+ requires Cypress 10.0.0+

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, cypress-grep

**Desired behavior:**
I'm trying to filter tests using the '@cypress/grep' plugin but getting incompatible error

**Command:**
npm run test:dev2 --env grep="Regression"

**Cypress Version:**
10.0.0

**Test script**

```js
it('Validate Default signature is being populated Reply to all email task (Regression,Sanity)',{tags: ['@Regression,@Sanity']}, () => {
    getWorkTab();
    waitUntilPageLoad();

    //open an email task
    filterWorkTypeAsEmail();
    cy.waitUntil(() => cy.get(Locators.taskColumn).should('contain.text', 'Email'));
    cy.get(Locator.taskCheckBox).eq(0).click();
    cy.get(Locator.taskContainer).last().dblclick({ force: true });

    //validate Default signature populating for ReplyAll
    cy.contains('Reply All').scrollIntoView().click();
    cy.get(Locators.subject).contains('RE:');
    cy.get(Locators.signatureEditor).its('0.contentDocument').its('body').contains('sh-etfswaps-settlements');
  });
```

**Error:**

> Error: Incompatible versions detected, cypress-grep 3.0.0+ requires Cypress 10.0.0+

Try:

I upgraded cypress version to 10.0.0 but still same Error: Incompatible versions detected, cypress-grep 3.0.0+ requires Cypress 10.0.0+ I am getting.

Comment: `cypress-grep` has been deprecated, and now should be installed as `@cypress/grep` instead. Here's a github link for the issue you're describing, where the end result is "this is deprecated, use the new install" -> https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep/issues/132 (You mention both install versions, but the error message includes `cypress-grep` which makes me think you've installed the deprecated version)

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue, both `cypress-grep` and `@cypress/grep` work with Cypress version 10.

Answer (score 3):

The older (deprecated) `cypress-grep` is still working with Cypress version 10.0.0.

The problem is that when you upgraded Cypress in `node_modules` you did not upgrade the `cypress.json` configuration to the newer `cypress.config.js` which is required by Cypress v10.

This is where the error message is thrown: [cypress-grep/src
/plugin.js](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-grep/blob/56afce9e920583d38ada30e13560e8372491d115/src/plugin.js#L20)

```js
  if (!config.specPattern) {
    throw new Error(
      'Incompatible versions detected, cypress-grep 3.0.0+ requires Cypress 10.0.0+ ',
    )
  }
```

This indicates the config is invalid, most likely because you need to upgrade as mention.

I recommend you start a new project folder, using the latest Cypress version and install `@cypress/grep` instead, because you will get many more features.